# Debugging buck converter IC having trouble reaching stable power good after short

Tags: power-supply, buck, debugging

I have a 5V power supply circuit from coming from a 12V in to 5V out of a TPS54620 on an FPGA development board I purchased. There was an incident with a bad header connection that caused a GPIO pin header's 5V rail to short to ground (and release some magic smoke from the pin headers). The board functions fine, however there's an issue after a few hours where the FPGA resets, which I attributed to a power issue. I did not observe any damage on any components, but I also do not have another board to compare against. My first thought was to begin checking power rails to see what's up.

Regulator Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps54620

The 12V IN appears fine, and the 3.3V and 1.8V regulators on this board are stable. However, the 5V rail is remaining too high (5.2V-5.3V) and has a lot of jitter. I have hooked up the PWRGD pin to my scope and I'm seeing that it is oscillating between logic 0 and 1. I am also seeing that V_SNS is remaining at about 0.82V and doesn't want to come down to VREF.

I am a beginner, so my knowledge of the theory here is not great. However, I'm still hoping to work through the process of narrowing down a cause of not reaching a stable power good. I assume this is a problem from the short, but it might have been a problem that already existed. I haven't started the process of pulling components off and checking them.

I did also find this post on the TI forums about a similar issue: https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/806624/tps54620-the-output-of-the-powergd-status-pin-is-constantly-changing-resulting-in-abnormal-monitoring-of-the-status-of-the-pin

What would be a few things an experienced debugger would be looking at to narrow down an issue with a switching power regulator to determine if there's a faulting component? Thank you!

Comment: Gbps - Hi, To comply with the SE [rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied or adapted from elsewhere, please add the *name* & *link* of the document (PDF perhaps?) which was the source of that schematic. TY

Comment: I have revised the post to remove potentially non-public information. Apologies!

Comment: Gbps - Oh dear. I don't know if it will be realistic to get help without the schematic. But perhaps I'm being too pessimistic - let's see whether site members can answer anyway.

Comment: @SamGibson Yeah, totally understandable. I was given the schematic with the board but didn't realize they don't post some of those files on their site. I will try to narrow it down further and then potentially retry the question with more specifics.